# how do I get a profile's "link" from Facebook's graph in a bash script?

Tags: facebook, bash

I'm trying to write a script that needs to extract a list of public facebook page URLs and stores them in a flat text file. I've already downloaded a few http://graph.facebook.com/$NUMBER files with wget, but I'm having trouble separating out the URL because of the weird delimiting that they use. Here's the general format (I'll use a fictitious example):

```
{"id":"4","name":"John Smith","first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/john.smith","username":"john.smith","gender":"male","locale":"en_US"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's JSON, and so your best bet is to use a tool that actually understands JSON. If you have python installed, it comes stock with json support, and so it's easy to do something like:

```
$ echo '{"id":"4","name":"John Smith","first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/john.smith","username":"john.smith","gender":"male","locale":"en_US"}' | python -c 'import json,sys; print json.load(sys.stdin)["link"]'
http://www.facebook.com/john.smith
```

Not a pure bash solution, but parsing JSON in bash seems like a lot of hard and unnecessary work, imo.

Comment: My God, that's kludgy, but it's a lot easier and more reliable than anything else I've come up with so far (and it actually works). Thanks!

Comment: @wafflesausage: If you want to make it less kludgy you can always put it in a script and clean it up a little and pipe to the script instead ;).

Comment: @wafflesausage: I removed a little unnecessary kludge that I spotted :D.